# Search results not pushing to MenuItem dropdown

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to push results (userNames from a table of Users) from a search function into a MenuItem dropdown. The search function is properly working and pulling the correct results, but I cannot figure out why the userNames from the results are not displaying in the MenuItem.

Here is the function that searches through the current list of users and pulls those that fit the criteria I need, and then pushes these results to the MenuItem:

```
private getActiveLsList = () => {
 const opts = new Array<React.ReactElement<any>>();

 const sr = new SearchRequest();
 sr.addFilter("role", "LoanSpecialist");
 sr.addFilter("ls_status", "Active");

 searchUsers(this.props.app.api, sr).then((res: SearchResults<User>) => {
  if (!res || !res.numHits || res.numHits < 1 || !res.results) {
    opts.push(
      <Select key="0" value="0">
        "Error loading LS List"
      </Select>
    );

    return opts;
  }

  res.results.forEach(n => {
    opts.push(
      <MenuItem key={n.id} value={n.id}>
        <Typography> {n.userName} </Typography>
      </MenuItem>
    );
  });

  return opts;
 });
};
```

Here is where I call the getActiveLsList function (within render):

```
       <TextField
          select
          fullWidth
          variant="outlined"
          value={this.state.assignedLS}
          onChange={this.updateAssignment("assigned_loan_specialist", "assignedLS")}
          margin="normal"
        >
          <MenuItem value="Unassigned">Unassigned</MenuItem>
          {this.getActiveLsList()}
        </TextField>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you at least need to re-organize a little bit like this:

```
state = {
  activeLsList: null,
}

private getActiveLsList = () => {
  const opts = new Array<React.ReactElement<any>>();

  const sr = new SearchRequest();
  sr.addFilter("role", "LoanSpecialist");
  sr.addFilter("ls_status", "Active");

  searchUsers(this.props.app.api, sr).then((res: SearchResults<User>) => {
    if (!res || !res.numHits || res.numHits < 1 || !res.results) {
      opts.push(
        <Select key="0" value="0">
          "Error loading LS List"
        </Select>
      );
    } else {
      res.results.forEach(n => {
        opts.push(
          <MenuItem key={n.id} value={n.id}>
            <Typography> {n.userName} </Typography>
          </MenuItem>
        );
      });
    }
    // use setState to correctly refresh the component after returning from async function
    this.setState({ activeLsList: opts });
  });
};

render() {
  // check before triggering the async function to prevent infinite loop
  if (!this.state.activeLsList) this.getActiveLsList();

  return (
    <TextField
      select
      fullWidth
      variant="outlined"
      value={this.state.assignedLS}
      onChange={this.updateAssignment("assigned_loan_specialist", "assignedLS")}
      margin="normal"
    >
      <MenuItem value="Unassigned">Unassigned</MenuItem>
      {this.state.activeLsList} // render from this.state
    </TextField>
  );
}
```

Comment: @J.Lara nice! ;)

Comment: So I created this same functionality for two more dropdowns (that live on the same webpage) to push two other sets of userName lists to two other dropdowns. Sometimes the dropdowns display the correct userNames, but most of the time, they contain userNames for all three dropdowns and they even sometimes repeat names. I've been troubleshooting this for a few days and can't figure it out. Any insight would be much appreciated!